# Apple wireless keyboard/mouse with 1.2V NiMH batteries

Tags: battery, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I have just invested in a set of 2460mAh rechargeable NiMH AA batteries for my Apple wireless mouse and keyboard - I felt a little guilty dumping the non-rechargeables in the bin.

However, I notice that these cells are rated 1.2V which I understand is common for NiMH and Lithium cells. The cells that ship with the mouse/keyboard are 1.5V so I want to be sure that these new batteries will still power these devices before I open the packaging.

Does anyone have experience of using these batteries successfully with these Apple products?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have specific experience with those products, but the type of battery you purchased is designed to do exactly what you intend. If you check the voltage of an alkaline battery after it's been used a while, you'll find that its voltage will have dropped below 1.5v. In fact, the voltage drops off faster for them than for NiMH batteries.

[image]

From the Wikipedia article on [rechargeable batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechargeable_battery):

> Also note that most NiMH AA or AAA batteries rate their cells at 1.2 volts. However, this is not a problem in most devices because alkaline batteries drop in voltage as the energy is depleted. Most devices will still operate with a voltage between 0.9 and 1.1 volts.

Here are a few articles to give you more information:

- [Why are rechargeable AA batteries 1.2v?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_are_rechargeable_AA_batteries_1.2V_instead_of_1.5V_like_alkaline_batteries)
- [Adventures in rechargeable batteries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001078.html) - Jeff Atwood on capacity and charging
- [Batteries Explained](http://www.component-shop.co.uk/html/batteries_explained.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad experience using rechargeable on apple Wireless keyboard but I can tell you that if you are using normal batteries it will take a very long time until you will have to replace them. This keyboards are very green even they are using Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine using Ni-MH batteries with this product, but be sure, you choose type with low self discharge, because some rechargeable batteries will self discharge in about 1 month. I am using Sanyo Eneloop (other companies make low self discharge batteries too). They are not so high capacity comparing to other brands, but when you use them after one year they are still full charged.

Answer (score -3):

Volt * Ampere = Watt.

Can't it be done the other way around?

Increase the use of (milli)Ampere (mA) in this Case and to get the same "power" than like from 1.5 Volt?

2.460 mAh * 1.2 Volt = 2.952 Wh (Watt Hours) or 2952 mWh?

Comment: Yes the amount of batteries is really little like that, I didn't knew before too as most people do not know. The usual US iPod user needs only 3.5 kWh/year for reloading. Samsung 1. generation smartphones had 4.44 Wh, my low-budget Huawei Ascend Y300's accu is 3.8V 2020mAh 7.7Wh (typ) but for my phone I think it is a bit reduced(?): Rated Capacity 1950 mAh 7.5 Wh, bought it a year ago new and cheap in Germany. Experts say smartphones save much energy, but not the 3.5 kWh reloading is the problem, the internet servers are consuming extreme amounts and in California they need heavy cooling...